# Issue with Upsert of TypeORM

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, typeorm

I'm trying to insert multiple JSON data into a table called **integration_data** using the TypeORM. I'm using NodeJS for my app. But somehow, I'm not able to form the query using TypeORM to perform bulk UpSert of my JSON data in Postgres SQL.

Following is my logic:-

```
let dbConn = await database.getConnection(connectionOptions);
             await dbConn.createQueryBuilder()
                 .insert()
                 .into(IntegrationData)
                 .values(rawdata)
                 .onConflict(`("id") DO UPDATE SET "empData" = excluded."empData"`)
                 .execute();
```

Here, I'm passing rawData which is an array of JSON objects.

**Entity:-**

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from "typeorm";

@Entity({ name: 'integration_data' })
export class IntegrationData {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ type: 'bigint', nullable: false, name: "emp_id" })
    empId: number;

    @Column({ type: 'text', nullable: false, name: "integration_name" })
    integrationName: string;

    @Column({ type: 'json', nullable: false, name: "emp_data" })
    empData: object

}
```

Here **emp_data** column in the **integration_data** table is of JSON. Following is my table on Postgres:-

[image]

May I know how can I perform an upsert operation i.e. insert if not exists else update the record in Postgres database based on **emp_id** which is going to be unique.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

You can use TypeORMs `Repository.save()` method to do upserts if the column is set as a primary key. You can simply pass an array of the objects into the method.

From the documentation:

```
 /**
 * Saves all given entities in the database.
 * If entities do not exist in the database then inserts, otherwise updates.
 */
```